# php://output and memory usage

Tags: php, performance, memory, memory-management, fopen

so I'm doing this in order to print out a csv file:

```
 while(ob_end_clean());
 $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
 fputcsv($fp, $header_fields);
  foreach($j as $fields){
    $row = array();
    foreach ($fields as $field){
      $row[] = $r->$field;
    }
    //stream each row
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
  }
  fclose($fp);
  exit;
```

My question is, suppose the csv will contain over 100,000 rows, will this cause an out of memory error or does this utilize the memory efficiently?

Comment: What's the purpose of the one-line `while (ob_end_clean())` up there?

Comment: What is your PHP [memory_limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) set to? Try it and see!